# PHP - Не выводится сообщение при неправильном пароле

Tags: php

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['email_log'])){
    $email_log = $_POST['email_log'];
}

if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","USER","MY_PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("mpp",$db);
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email_log'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$password="SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$pass'";
$result_pass=mysql_query($password);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$email_log', '$pass')");
}
else {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result_pass)==$pass){ 
           $_SESSION['msg'] = "Incorrect password!";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/resize.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<? include("blocks/header.php")?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="loginform">
<label class="box_email_log" for="email_log"><div class="email_log_text">Email:</div></label>
<input type="email" name="email_log" id="email_log" value="" maxlength="50" required>
<label class="box_pass" for="pass"><div class="pass_text">Password:</div></label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="8-20" pattern="[\S\s]{8,20}" required>
<input class="submit_pass" type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit">
<div class="box_result_pass"><div class="result_pass"><? if (!empty($_SESSION['msg'])) { echo $_SESSION['msg']; $_SESSION['msg'] = ''; } ?></div></div>
</form>
<? include("blocks/slide.php")?>
<? include("blocks/footer.php")?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не используйте функции `mysql_`, их нет в php7.

Comment: Что тут за дичь вообще происходит с созданием логина в таблице, если его не нашлось? И с паролями дичь какая-то... Ни тебе шифрования, ни тюбе защиты от SQL-инъекций. Что вы хотите вообще сделать???

Answer (score 0):

1. [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.su/mysql_num_rows) возвращает количество рядов результата запроса. Если вернуло нуль, то и должно сравниваться с нулём
2. `if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)` если нет в БД зачем его регистрировать с паролем. И проверка на аутентификацию должна быть "Неверный логин или пароль"
3. Нет старта сессии [session_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Прописал session_start, все равно не выводится. Если если вместо $_SESSION пишу echo, то выводит. Но мне нужно, чтоб выводился блок. В чем причина?

Comment: в  if(mysql_num_rows($result_pass)==$pass) попадает?